# What could cause eclipse to display two "Source" menus for Java files?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse 2023-06 and Eclipse 2023-09, the top menu displays two "Source" menus when I have a Java file opened. The first menu is what I would expect, and the second contains only one option "Format", which is also greyed-out.

This prevents me from using the shortcut *alt + shift + s* to open the Source menu.

**First menu**

[image: Screenshot of the Eclipse top menus, with the two Source menus displayed. The first Source menu is opened, displaying all expected options, like "Toggle comment", "Add block comment", "Format", etc.]

**Second menu**
[image: Screenshot of the Eclipse top menus, with the two Source menus displayed. The second Source menu is opened, displaying only the option, "Format", that is also disabled]

The second "Source" menu disappears when I'm editing other files, like XML or properties files.

**What could be causing this?**

- I tried resetting the key bindings, which didn't work.
- Using *right-click > open with... > Java editor* doesn't work either.
- Using *right-click > open with... > Generic text editor* made the first "Source" menu disappear, leaving only the second, that only contains the disabled "Format" option.

Comment: I can not reproduce it. Is this a fresh installation? Can this be reproduced with a fresh workspace? Does _Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective..._ fix it?

Comment: @howlger Resetting the perspective didn't fix it. It's not a fresh installation.

I tried a fresh installation and the extra menu was not there... until I installed my plugins. So I suppose it's one of my plugins fault. I'll try to find which one.

Comment: @howlger It's [Spring Tools 4](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4). Can you try reproducing it? If you are able to, I'll try finding the maintainers and report the issue.

Comment: Obviously a plugin contributes a second _Source_ menu instead of using the existing one. Which of your plugin does it cause? Please report it to the plugin owner. As Workaround you can disable the second _Source_ menu which might contain items in certain cases via _Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective..._, tab _Menu Visibility_.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1111

Comment: You said "... until I installed my plugins". Did you install only Spring Tools or are you sure Spring Tools is the plugin that causes it?

Comment: Yes. I reproduced this issue on a clean install adding only Spring Tools 4, both on Windows and MacOS.

Comment: I see, [the issue has already been confirmed by the STS4 lead developer](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1111#issuecomment-1727545117) so it will be probably be fixed soon. Thanks for reporting. Please consider to give a self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, [a plugin was adding the extra Source menu](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1111). The plugin was [Spring Tools 4](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4).

Thanks @howlger for helping with the troubleshooting on my side.